# parentheses when printing list

Tags: python, list, tuples, python-unicode

This is not sqlite specific, but it I wondered while learning python and sqlite3 and listing the results of query. I have simple code:

```
connection = sqlite3.connect("db.sqlite")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from db")
print cursor.fetchall()
```

So, the results of the `print cursor.fetchall()` is: `[(u'koko',), (u'lolo',)]`
But, when I try to recreate that kind of print with this code:

```
i=["koko","lolo"]
print i
```

the print result is: `['koko', 'lolo']`

Two things I don't understand:

1. why the first list has 'u' for unicode when printing and second doesn't?
2. why the first list has parenthesis `(u'koko',)` when printing and second doesn't?

Is the first list a list of tuples maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[(u'koko',), (u'lolo',)]` is a list of 1-element tuples of unicode strings.

`["koko","lolo"]` is a list of byte strings.

Comment: @cikatomo You can make a string a unicode literal by using `u'some string'` for a literal, or using the `unicode()` built-in. Alternatively, use Python 3.x where all strings are Unicode by default. It's worth noting that in general, unicode strings and byte strings work anywhere the other will work (except in a few cases or, naturally, where you need unicode characters).

Comment: If you wanted to make the same thing, why didn't you just copy it? It's exactly what it looks like.

Comment: The point of `repr(x)` is that if you paste the resultant string into code, it should produce `x`. (Given the correct imports and the class implementing `repr()` correctly).

Answer (score 3):

The list has parenthesis because that is how python prints a `tuple`.

Contrast:

```
a = 'foo'
print a,type(a)
```

with:

```
b = ('foo',)
print b,type(b)
```

Also note that in python2.x, there are different types of strings.  `unicode` is just a type of string, and python chooses to represent that as `u'whatever'`:

```
>>> print u'whatever'
whatever
>>> print repr(u'whatever')
u'whatever'
```

Note that `str(tup)` implicitly calls `repr` on each element in the tuple.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to manipulate the results to adapt it to the format you want...

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()
result = [elem[0] for elem in rows]
```

...and maybe to apply a function to elem[0] (depending on your python version) to put the strings in the format you want to.